# How to merge columns into one from different dataframes in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have five different dataframes, each one with a single column.

I want to create a new dataframe, with a single column made by the merge of the five columns mentioned before.

It is a simple problem, but i am a new user of R

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So there's a couple of easy ways to do this -

My preferred way would be to use the dplyr package from the tidyverse, as it would then allow you (in my opinion) to do further data wrangling if needed a little easier. The code for that would be:

```r
library(tidyverse)
new.dataframe <- bind_rows(df1, df2, df3)
```

where df1, df2 etc are your existing dataframes you want to combine and this would form a new dataframe called new.dataframe.

You could also use rbind in base R, doing:

```r
new.dataframe <- rbind(df1, df2, df2)
```

Hope that helps!